# Entity Framework one foreign key map to multiple tables

Tags: entity-framework

Hello suppose I am using Entity Framework Core and have some classes like:

```
class A {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string PropA { get; set;}
}
class B {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public int PropB { get; set;}
}
class C {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime PropC {get; set;}
}
class Log {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public Guid ObjectId {get; set;}
    public DateTime UpdateDate {get; set;}
}
```

Where class Log will store the class A B C's Id to field ObjectId.
What I want to achieve is to retrieve rows of A/B/C which updated after specific date time. I come up in mind to edit the classes by adding 
`List<Log>` to the classes like:

```
class A {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string PropA { get; set;}
    public List<Log> Log { get; set;}
}
```

But I don't know whether it is correct. Is this the proper way to model such relationship?
Thanks.

Comment: no problem for me.But use like this `public List<Log> Logs { get; set;}` Do you have any issues ?

Comment: @Sampath Thank you for your reply. In fact it was perfectly okay. Since I am not an expert in EF so I have doubt and seek for any advice / best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see any implementation issues on the above use case.But you have to use naming conversions properly when you named the properties.

Here is the issue on list naming.

**BAD :** `public List<Log> Log { get; set;}`

**BEST :** `public List<Log> Logs { get; set;}`